Update column based on value of another column
I need to update a column called "ISP_GROUP" in my MySQL table based on the values of the "EMAIL" column in the same table.
I have done this in Excel.  I used the below formula to populate values of the ISP_GROUP column based on the values in the A column, which are EMAILS:
=IF(COUNTIF(A2,"*@gmail.com*"),"GM",
 IF(COUNTIF(A2,"*@yahoo.com*"),"VMG",
 IF(COUNTIF(A2,"*@aol.com*"),"VMG",
 IF(COUNTIF(A2,"*@sbcglobal.net*"),"VMG",
 IF(COUNTIF(A2,"*@att.net*"),"VMG",
 IF(COUNTIF(A2,"*@ymail.com*"),"VMG",
 IF(COUNTIF(A2,"*@rocketmail.com*"),"VMG",
 IF(COUNTIF(A2,"*@aim.com*"),"VMG",
 IF(COUNTIF(A2,"*@verizon.net*"),"VMG",
 IF(COUNTIF(A2,"*@hotmail.com*"),"MSFT",
 IF(COUNTIF(A2,"*@live.com*"),"MSFT",
 IF(COUNTIF(A2,"*@msn.com*"),"MSFT",
 IF(COUNTIF(A2,"*@outlook.com*"),"MSFT",
 IF(COUNTIF(A2,"*@passport.com*"),"MSFT", "other" ))))))))))))))

So the formula above will look at the EMAIL in the first column.  And then, for example, if the email is a "@gmail.com" account, set the ISP_GROUP value to GM.
I can no longer complete this task in Excel as the amount of records in the CSV exceed the amount that Excel can handle.
So now I have to import the CSV directly into my MySQL table, and then update the values after they have uploaded.
I just have no idea how to write the above formula in a MySQL update statement.
So the query will start like this:
UPDATE `table` SET `ISP_GROUP` = 'SOMETHING TO MIMIC THE ABOVE FORMULA';

I am not sure how to convert the Excel formula to a query in MySQL.
Right now, the table looks like this:
|     EMAIL     | ISP_GROUP |
-----------------------------
| k@hotmail.com |           |
| j@gmail.com   |           |
| f@aol.com     |           |
| p@usa.com     |           |
-----------------------------

The query that I need to write will update the ISP_GROUP like this:
|     EMAIL     | ISP_GROUP |
-----------------------------
| k@hotmail.com |   MFT     |
| j@gmail.com   |   GM      |
| f@aol.com     |   VMG     |
| p@usa.com     |   OTHER   |
-----------------------------


can you provide an example of your input and expected output?

why not create a reference table and join them?

@tacoshy - are you suggesting that I create an "ISP_GROUP" table that holds just the different ISP types and then join them?  Wouldn't I still need to have something that will mark each type to each email?

yes, but that would be a one-liner then and could be included in the original SQL request.

This should be just  a (relatively) simple case statement, no?  case when   upper(<email>) like '%GMAIL.COM' then 'GM'...

UPDATE `table`
SET `ISP_GROUP` = 
    CASE
        WHEN `EMAIL` LIKE '%@gmail.com%' THEN 'GM'
        WHEN `EMAIL` LIKE '%@yahoo.com%' THEN 'VMG'
        WHEN `EMAIL` LIKE '%@aol.com%' THEN 'VMG'
        WHEN `EMAIL` LIKE '%@sbcglobal.net%' THEN 'VMG'
        WHEN `EMAIL` LIKE '%@att.net%' THEN 'VMG'
        WHEN `EMAIL` LIKE '%@ymail.com%' THEN 'VMG'
        WHEN `EMAIL` LIKE '%@rocketmail.com%' THEN 'VMG'
        WHEN `EMAIL` LIKE '%@aim.com%' THEN 'VMG'
        WHEN `EMAIL` LIKE '%@verizon.net%' THEN 'VMG'
        WHEN `EMAIL` LIKE '%@hotmail.com%' THEN 'MFT'
        WHEN `EMAIL` LIKE '%@live.com%' THEN 'MFT'
        WHEN `EMAIL` LIKE '%@msn.com%' THEN 'MFT'
        WHEN `EMAIL` LIKE '%@outlook.com%' THEN 'MFT'
        WHEN `EMAIL` LIKE '%@passport.com%' THEN 'MFT'
        ELSE 'OTHER'
    END;

Please try the above sql code.

Basically correct, just some notes: 1) Take care about casing. Would be safer to write LOWER(EMAIL). 2) Depending on the amount of rows, this could be very slow due to all those LIKE conditions. In this case, it would be faster to skip the entire CASE expression and rather run separate update commands with each condition as WHERE clause. 3) This ugly way to fix the data should be one time job and not be repeated. In future, better improve the DB structure.

Those same VMG can be shorten to WHEN EMAIL REGEXP '@yahoo.com|@aol.com|@sbcglobal.net|@att.net|@ymail.com|@rocketmail.com|@aim.com|@verizon.net' THEN 'VMG' ...
